# Salesforce Packages not Visible even after 5 hours of uploading

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package

I am trying to Install a package that was created about 5 hours back.

Below is the Error:
Package Installation Details
Help for this Page
Invalid Package
This package is not yet available. Please try again later or contact the package owner.

1) Is it the Issue with NA 9 which is used (in m case) to create a package or is it something to do with salesforce taking time to propagate.
Package was unavailable on NA 13, 14 and 7.

2) Or IS it something different for Beta and release packages availability?

Comment: Unless it failed to upload, it will eventually be available. This is the second such question to appear about slow replication times this release. I would hypothesize that right after a release is probably a heavy load time, since many vendors schedule their release cycles to coincide with salesforce's.

Comment: Seeing the same error for a package uploaded from NA15...so I think it is a system wide thing...

Comment: We had change sets from na1 and cs12 taking forever today

Comment: I've been waiting around 15 hours for one now

Comment: maybe related to this issue ? https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyO6AAK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are experiencing this same issue again:
This issue happens if:
1) The package is recently created (give it a few hours to propagate to all types of instances and might be between 2 to 24 hours)
2) If you are in the middle of the Major release schedule.
https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/
(Some orgs are upgraded early for eg Winter 14 release schedule upgrades NA1 and NA10 on Oct 19 and Oct 20 whereas if your org starts with any one of CS3 CS7 CS9 CS11 then you will be force upgraded on November 23 and November 24.)

Answer (score 6):

I've created several cases on this problem in the last few weeks.

Although I personally don't like the answer, one eventually came back from salesforce support that "at present there is no SLA on the installation process". There are a few more details here [Managed packages can take hours to become available](http://force201.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/managed-packages-can-take-hours-to-become-available/).

I guess the next step is to find another channel to use to get the message over to salesforce that these delays are causing many of us pain.

Comment: I've said this before (but I can't seem to find it now), but the *Help & Training* specifically states that it may take over **168 hours** (a week!), so you must be patient.

Comment: It was a Salesforce release week so it took time for the packages to propagate on different instances as its a one week schedule to update all instances. Also it generally takes 0 to 24 hours for a package to be available (generally 0 to 1 hour).

Answer (score 1):

Package upload and availability time epends on package size and salesforce server availability. If you are waiting from last 48 hours. Then you should raise a case with salesforce.